# Why is $(\int dx)^2 = \int dx \int dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, quantum-mechanics, gaussian-integral

An exercise in a quantum mechanics book:

Show that

$$ G(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}ax^2} = \sqrt\frac{2\pi}{a}$$

Solution

$$G(a)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty  dy\space e^{-\frac{a}{2}(x^2+y^2)} = \space ...$$

Why is $G(a)^2$ equal to an integral of $dx$ and $dy$?

**Edit/Note:** this is a Gausian integral. This solution is also used on [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral#Computation).

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are dummy variables, so$$G(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}ax^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}ay^2} \, \mathrm{d}y.$$Multiply these two identical quantities together to get $G(a)^2$.

Comment: Also isn't it more correct to write

$$G(a)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \int_{-\infty}^\infty \space e^{-\frac{a}{2}(x^2+y^2)}\ dx\ dy  = \space ...$$

as opposed to

$$G(a)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty  dy\space e^{-\frac{a}{2}(x^2+y^2)} = \space ...$$

?

Comment: $(\int dx)^2=(\int dx)(\int dx)=(\int dx)(\int dy)$ since $x,y$ are dummy

Comment: @AdamRubinson Both notations are widely used.

Comment: @TheoBendit if you write your original comment as an answer, I'll accept it. I indeed didn't realize that $dx = dy$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson $\int f(x)\;dx$ is usually used in mathematics.  But $\int dx\;f(x)$ is used in some engineering or physics settings.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Comment: It is not correct to say $dx = dy$.  But it is correct to change a dummy variable to any other variable.

Comment: Whilst this is obviously a much more simple example, it is the same thing as saying let $x=y$ now you can say $f^2(x)=f(x)f(y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this a bit more generally. We have a function of $a$ of the form
$$
G(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,a)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Note that the "$x$" here as a integration variable is just bound inside the integral, so equivalently we can write this as
$$
G(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau,a)\,\mathrm d\tau,
$$
or indeed any other symbol instead of $x$ or $\tau$. This is analogous to summation indices:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^3 a_k = a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = \sum_{n=1}^3 a_n,
$$
it doesn't matter if the index is called $k$ or $n$, as long as it's used consistently.

Now squaring $f(a)$ yields
$$
G(a)^2 = \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau,a)\,\mathrm d\tau\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau,a)\,\mathrm d\tau\right).
$$
We can now rename one of the indices (back) to $x$ and the other $y$:
$$
G(a)^2 = \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,a)\,\mathrm dx\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y,a)\,\mathrm dy\right).
$$
To go from this to a double integral, we treat one as a constant factor and use linearity of the integral: $c\int \dots\,\mathrm dx = \int c(\dots)\,\mathrm dx$. This then yields
$$
G(a)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \underbrace{\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y,a)\,\mathrm dy\right)}_c f(x,a)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Again $f(x,a)$ may now be treated as a constant factor to the $\mathrm dy$-integral and we get
$$
G(a)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,a)f(y,a)\,\mathrm dy\right) \,\mathrm dx.
$$
This is the double integral you encountered and in a notation used mostly by physicists that treats $\int\mathrm dx$ as an operator applied from the left, this is written as
$$
G(a)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm dy\  f(x,a)f(y,a).
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you write it in terms of Riemann's integral definition, it boils down to:
$$(\sum_i a_i)(\sum_j b_j)=\sum_{ij}a_ib_j$$